# with my 32 bit windows 7, with python 3.7 getting error "No module named 'prometheus_client'

Tags: python, 32-bit

with my 32 bit windows 7, with python 3.7 getting error "No module named 'prometheus_client'  when installed with command `>pip install prometheus_client` it shows Successfully installed prometheus-client

```
C:\>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\varda\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py",
line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\varda\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\runpy.py",
line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\varda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\jupyter
-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\varda\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 79, in <module>
    from .base.handlers import Template404, RedirectWithParams
  File "c:\users\varda\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packag
es\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 32, in <module>
    import prometheus_client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prometheus_client'
```

Comment: here i meant python 3.7 not python 7

Comment: You most likely have multiple python versions installed and pip is installing to one and the PATH references another. Is it safe to assume that you are not using a virtual environment?

Comment: Yes, i'm not using virtual environment. I did install 3.7 at different location first then changed the location later but always same version i.e. 3.7. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Sandip when replying to somebody use the AT sign e.g.   @nicholishen   so he knows you replied to him